# How to add arguments to the custom action exe in Wix?

Tags: wix, custom-action, burn, windows-installer

I am trying to execute an exe after installation. Below is how I am trying to do this.

```
 <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchMosquitto" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="LaunchMosquitto" After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In here, [#fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D] refers to the file ID. I need to run this exe with the parameter " -c config.conf". How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated. I need this to happen without a command prompt being launched.

Logs after the answer :

```
MSI (s) (D0:24) [18:32:16:273]: Executing op:  ActionStart(Name=LaunchMosquitto,,)
MSI (s) (D0:24) [18:32:16:273]: Executing op:  CustomActionSchedule(Action=LaunchMosquitto,ActionType=3137,Source=BinaryData,Ta rget=WixQuietExec64,CustomActionData="C:\Kube2.0\Mosquitto\mosquitto.exe" -c  C:\Kube2.0\Mosquitto\mosquitto.conf)
```

Comment: This article in the manual should answer your questions: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html. Especially, the "Deferred Execution" section

Answer (score 0):

As Yan suggested you should use a quiet CA.

```
<SetProperty Id="LaunchMosquitto" Value="&quot;[#fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D]&quot; -c config.conf" Before="LaunchMosquitto" Sequence="execute"/>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchMosquitto"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="WixQuietExec64"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchMosquitto" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Hey its running the command successfully and the process has started. But the installation won't complete! I guess that's because of the spawned process? Any ideas?

Comment: change Return="ignore"

Comment: Yes mate, tried that too. Still the same issue persists.

Comment: Check the log file while installing, you will see why the installation does not complete. Also you can Change the ignore to asyncNoWait, in that case the installer will not wait for return error.

Comment: I have edited the question with my logs. There's nothing printed on the logs after the above lines. I cannot use AsnycNoWait along with Property Value element. If I remove this and go for that, I get a terminal being launched everytime the installer tries to execute the exe. Totally stuck mate! :(