# Pass command-line arguments to WiX custom action

Tags: wix, exe, command-line-arguments, custom-action

We have a desktop application installed through a windows installer (msi), and we want to add a custom action that relaunches the .exe when we have pass `LAUNCH_APP=1` to the `cmd`.

So I have a vbs script that launch a bat file that launch install the msi (major upgrade):

vbs script:

```vbs
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tempFolder: tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
WshShell.Run chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & chr(34) & chr(32) & chr(34) & tempFolder & "\Lifen\update\LifenInstaller.msi" & chr(34) & chr(32) & chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(1) & chr(34), 0, True
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

bat script:

```
@echo off 

call :start >%APPDATA%\Lifen\batMsiLog.log

:start
wmic process where "name='Lifen.exe'" delete
start /wait msiexec /i %1 /qn /norestart /log %APPDATA%\Lifen\msilog.log LAUNCH_APP=1
```

And in my wix installer (wix version 3.1.0) has this custom action:

```
<Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value='"[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe"'/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecRestartApp" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="QtExecRestartApp" After="InstallFinalize">LAUNCHAPP = 1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I don't know how to add an argument (like `—new-version`) to my custom action to relaunch my exe.

In the end, I would like to run the command:

`Lifen.exe —new-version`

I tried various ways to write it:

- `'"[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe --new-version=x.x.x"'`
- `'"[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe" "--new-version=x.x.x"'`

or also after reading this stackoverflow : [How to add arguments to the custom action exe in Wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575629/how-to-add-arguments-to-the-custom-action-exe-in-wix)

- `'"&quot;[#"[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe"]"&quot; "--new-version"'`
- `'"&quot;[#"[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe"]"&quot; "--new-version"'`

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

## Basic Syntax

```
<Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value='"[INSTALLFOLDER]Lifen.exe" --new-version'/>
```

- You always need to **quote paths**, because they may contain spaces.
- You **don't need a backslash after folder properties** like `[INSTALLFOLDER]`, because the MSI runtime makes sure that the values of all installation folder properties end with backslash.
- **Same for the arguments, you need to quote if they may contain spaces**. If you have a constant argument like `--new-version` where you know for sure that there are no spaces, you don't need to quote. For arguments that contain property references, it's safer to always quote. E. g.:

  ```
  <Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value='"[INSTALLFOLDER]Lifen.exe" "--new-version=[NEWVERSION]"'/>
  ```

If you are in doubt, have a look into the **verbose log** to see if the actual value of `WixQuietExecCmdLine` is what you expect. Activate verbose logging by calling `msiexec -l*v logfile.txt <OtherParameters>`.

## 64-Bit Executables

To run 64-bit executables, use the `WixQuietExec64` custom action and `WixQuietExec64CmdLine` property instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried with verbose logs and as you specified but I can see in the logs that :

Comment: Property(S): WixQuietExecCmdLine = "[INSTALLFOLDER]Lifen.exe" --new-version
Property(S): WixShellExecTarget = "[INSTALLFOLDER]\Lifen.exe"

Comment: The 1st line is the specific custom action with LAUNCH_APP.
The 2nd line is another custom action that launches the app after the installation.

It is detail and I read what you said about \ and writing [INSTALLFOLDER]Lifen.exe but it does not change anything..

Do you have any other idea why it is not working ?

Comment: @ValentineLanger Oh well, how I didn't see that. When the value of a property contains references to other properties, it can't be set through `<Property ...>`. This doesn't resolve the property references, as can be seen from your log. You need to use `<SetProperty ...>` instead. See example at the [documentation page](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html). Everything else I wrote still holds true.