# Command-line argument syntax for WiX custom action SetProperty

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wix, action, silent

I am an implementer that has occasionally created installers over the last 6+ years but I am still not great at creating installers, especially compared to most on this forum.

I am trying to create an msi that follows up an install of the Pulse Secure VPN client and adds a config file then runs the existing Pulse Secure program `jamCommand.exe` with the switch `-importfile` then the config file `PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig` (*in this case*) which populates 2 connection profiles in Pulse Secure.  I have spent so much time trying to get this to work (*16+ hours*) and have tried so many things from many different pages here.

I have tried going about it two ways, and can easily get the msi to place the config/batch files in the `JamUI` folder but cannot get either msi to actually run the command with switches at the end of the install. Early on, I created a batch file that runs the command perfectly in x86/x64 Windows.  I know the batch option isn't ideal, but I had already tried the various silent install options with equal failure.  Here is all of the applicable code and I think I am close with one of them, having tried well over 50 variations of the code (*trying different combos of* `'`, `"` *and* `&quot;`) and then running the msi in a clean VM snapshot.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891721/pass-command-line-arguments-to-wix-custom-action) is the closest to an answer to my particular problem, but in my case it seems to be an issue calling the existing `jamCommand.exe` correctly.  Verbose logging of the install hasn't been helpful because it doesn't seem to even know any command was attempted (*at least to my unexperienced eye*).

Here is the code, including the batch file:

PSC_Both.bat (Works great)

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\Pulse.exe" goto 64BIT
 :64BIT
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\jamCommand.exe" -importfile PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig
else
 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\jamCommand.exe" -importfile PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig
```

QUIET INSTALL VERSION

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
<Directory Id="CommonFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="PULSESECURE" Name="Pulse Secure">
        <Directory Id="JAMUI" Name="JamUI" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="JAMUI">
    <Component Id="PSC_Affil_Both" Guid="fe6e562f-3ce1-489e-b467-810fc3f2d352">
        <File Id="PSC_Affil_Both" Source="..\PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig" DiskId='1' KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component> 
</DirectoryRef>

        <Feature Id='PSConfigs64' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='PSC_Affil_Both' />
        </Feature>
  </Product>
   <Fragment>
<SetProperty Id="ConfigBoth64CMD" Value='"[#"[JamUI]jamCommand.exe"]" "-importfile PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig"' Before="ConfigBoth64CMD" />
<CustomAction Id="ConfigBoth64CMD"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="WixQuietExec"
          Execute="deferred"
          Return="check"
              Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ConfigBoth64CMD" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
   </Fragment>
```

RUN BATCH FILE VERSION

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
<Directory Id="CommonFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="PULSESECURE" Name="Pulse Secure">
        <Directory Id="JAMUI" Name="JamUI" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="JAMUI">
    <Component Id="PSC_Affil_Both" Guid="fe6e562f-3ce1-489e-b467-810fc3f2d352">
        <File Id="PSC_Affil_Both" Source="..\PSC_Affil_Both.jnprpreconfig" DiskId='1' KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component> 
    <Component Id="PSC_Both" Guid="fba7131d-8644-48a2-91e8-5235a45d4c1a">
        <File Id="PSC_Both" Source="..\PSC_Both.bat" DiskId='1' KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component> 

</DirectoryRef>
        <Feature Id='PSConfigs64' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='PSC_Affil_Both' />
      <ComponentRef Id='PSC_Both' />
        </Feature>
  </Product>
<Fragment>
<CustomAction Id="RunBatch"               
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="ignore"             
                  Impersonate="no"              
                  ExeCommand='/C [JAMUI]PSC_Both.bat'
                  Directory="JAMUI"/> 
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunBatch" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>   
</Fragment>
```

Other than the one post, I cannot find a lot of actual code samples of the command line part. Any help or suggestions would be so appreciated :)

Comment: The batch-file code has an `else` keyword that seems like a syntax issue. I would expect the last batch-file line to be above the `:64BIT` label and add a line to prevent a fall through into the :64BIT label.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, I will try that.  As part of trying many variant ways of running it, I did try it with a bat file that only had the 64-bit Windows command, but I didn't find success either way.  I also tried including variations of the full path to the jamCommand.exe in the command line for both methods, although that seemed unnecessary since the path to the folder is already defined in the upper code.  It seems like the issue is some command line combo that I didn't try in the quiet install and that is the one that I prefer to get working since it negates the need for a bat.